# Entering MASSIVE Data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've faced up a problem with uploading a data in MySQL base.
well, I have over **37 million** randomly generated codes (8 digit).

I want to upload them in MySQL in the defined tables. What I mean is that I want to sort the codes by its beginning letter and upload in the corresponding table
for example:
if the codes starts with **W**, it needs to be uploading in **W_codes** table
if the codes starts with **1**, it needs to be uploading in **1_codes** table
and so on...

I had a C# program which did the sorting itself and uploading the codes to MySQL but it takes over 6-7 hours per 1 million codes.

Do you have any more simple idea how to do sorting and then upload the codes in the corresponded table?
MySQL .sql upload size limit is 128MB..

any ideas?

Comment: wondering - is the insert batched or is it one insert per code

Comment: Why not generate the code in SQL? Should be much faster

Comment: Well, the codes are already generated and I can't change them as they are sent to production... btw, there was a some reason why i didn't generated them in PHP.

Insert is ONE insert per code as I assume. one code is on one line, in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think partitioning codes this way does not make much sense to me.  Time or geocode partitioning would make more sense.

A design like this certainly breaks some normalization rules.  There ought to be one relation for your codes.

37 million isn't that big a number for a database.  Why do you think you need to do this?

I'd load them all into a single table in the database and see how it performed.  You don't say if the table has other values, if the codes are primary keys, or what the WHERE clauses you use to access the data look like.  Maybe you just didn't index the table properly. That'll make a huge difference in query times.

Are the codes static and read-only?  Or do you write to this table as well?

If I had to resort to a scheme like the one you're describing, I'd use the database itself to SELECT data into the partitioned tables.  Databases are optimized to do this sort of thing.

Comment: So you mean that I'd upload all the 37 million codes with one file at MySQL, insert it in one table and then Partition it by first letter in corresponding tables with SELECT? right? that really makes sense..

P.S. they had to be partitioned as the PHP codes works that way.
before this, when I made to check the entered code in one table with 37 million file it overloaded the server. as the requests were more than 2000 a day. so going through 37 million codes 2000 times lagged the server

Comment: That's one suggestion.  I would not think that 2000 queries on a table of 37 million rows would lag any server.  You should EXPLAIN PLAN on your query and see if you're doing TABLE SCAN.  If yes, add indexes for columns in WHERE clauses.  You don't say if the table is transactional, read-only, or read-mostly.  That makes a difference, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following.
Create a temp table. Insert all codes into the temp table in a single batch.
Query the temptable to insert into the other tables based on the first character. A simple where clause should do the trick, nothing complicated. Shouldn't take to long it's only 37 million records.

Comment: yeah, I got the idea..
but should all this codes (lines) has the special format to be inserted into tables?